# Localization in PlaylistItems YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an application that uses the YouTube API to display a list of playlists and videos from a particular YouTube Channel. The application supports multiple languages so I also used the localizations feature YouTube API offers and it works great with `v3/videos` and `v3/playlists` using the `hl` param, but the only problem I faced was with `v3/playlistItems` as it doesn't have support for localizations.

Please help me in adding localizations using `v3/playlistItems` so that all videos under a particular playlist displays localized title and description.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly work around is to send two requests. First fetch the video-ids by using `v3/playlistItems`, then use `v3/videos` with the video-ids separated by comma, to get the translation with the available `hl` param.

Comment: To streamline this a bit, here are two URLs to help the next person get started. 

_Note: for my application, I only need to fetch the titles so I added an optional `fields` query parameter to keep the response size small._

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&fields=pageInfo,items(snippet(resourceId/videoId))&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLAYLIST_ID&key=KEY&hl=LANGUAGE_CODE

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID_1,VIDEO_ID_2,VIDEO_ID_3&key=KEY&hl=LANGUAGE_CODE&fields=pageInfo,items(id,snippet(localized.title))

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no indicated way of doing this from the [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) docs. Try filing for a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).